# Laravel - View [events.index] not found error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I'm having another issue with a view. I've set up my routes correctly and in my index function I've added the right view, so I have no clue why it isn't working. I am making a calendar app and I've had a few issues which I've fixed but I can't get this one sorted.

Controller file:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('events.index', EventsResource::collection(Events::all()));
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('events/', 'Events\EventsController@index')->name('events');
```

Error:

```
View [events.index] not found.
```

My file structure for "views" looks like this:

```
views
-events
--index.blade.php
welcome.blade.php
```

so I have absolutely no clue why it can't find the view when it clearly exists.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use name space or prefix for route group in web.php?

Comment: `require base_path('routes/web/events.php');` - that's in my web.php, I use directories to manage the amount of routes

Comment: run ```php artisan route:list``` and tell what returns

Comment: Try to clear the view cache: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I've cleared the cache a lot of times. With "php artisan route:list", it listed all of my routes besides the events routes.

Comment: What is your laravel version?

Comment: it's version 7.1

Comment: And the `views` folder is inside the `resources` folder, which is in your basefolder for the installation?

Comment: views folder is in resources yes

Comment: Can you paste ```web.php``` and ```web/events.php``` code please?